# Display category names on edit user profile using $wpdb

Tags: wpdb

On the 'Edit Profile' page I'm trying to loop through all the category names using $wpdb. Here is my code

```
<?php
function custom_user_profile_fields($profileuser) {
?>
<h1>Select a Category</h1>
<select name="category">
  <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $terms = $wpdb->query( "SELECT name FROM wp_terms" );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
      <option value=""><?php echo $term; ?></option>
    <?php }
  ?>
</select>
<?php
}
add_action('show_user_profile', 'custom_user_profile_fields');
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'custom_user_profile_fields');
```

But I'm getting empty option filed.

Comment: use inbuilt **wp_dropdown_categories** 
 [https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories] function . It would be the better option than $wpdb SQL query

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Previously I have done this using `get_terms` but I really need this using $wpdb for a specific reason.

Comment: try $wpdb->get_results instead of $wpdb->query . Hopefully it would work.

Comment: Thank you so much! Though got a fatal error but at least I got few text which is really helpful.

Comment: You will double check your PHP code. It will not produce any PHP fatal error

Comment: You are right! I was missing the field name "name" `<?php echo $term->name; ?>` Thank you so much!

Comment: "I really need this using $wpdb for a specific reason" What reason?

Comment: The reason is nothing secrete, I'm just learning this topic (wpdb) and trying to accomplish previously completed task in this different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$wpdb->query()` method doesn't return query results but a count on how many rows were affected by the query. To get the results you have to user the `$wpdb->get_results($sqlString)` method and then iterate over it.

```php
<?php
function custom_user_profile_fields($profileuser) {
?>
<h1>Select a Category</h1>
<select name="category">
  <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $terms = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT name FROM wp_terms" );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
      <option value=""><?php echo $term->name; ?></option>
    <?php }
  ?>
</select>
<?php
}
add_action('show_user_profile', 'custom_user_profile_fields');
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'custom_user_profile_fields');
```